# Class.forName() and ClassNotFoundException

Tags: java, exception, classloader

Say I have the following two classes:

```
public class MyClass {
    public String getDescription() {
        return "MyClass";
    }
}
```

and

```
public class MyClassLoader {
    public static void main (String[] argv) throws ClassNotFoundException {
        Class.forName("MyClass");
        System.out.println("MyClass class was successfully loaded");
    }
}
```

If both of these classes are in the default package, it runs fine, the class loads, and the world is beautiful.  (If I were to delete the class `MyClass`, I would get a `ClassNotFoundException`, as expected.

However, if they are both in a package (let's say it's a package in Eclipse), and have the

```
package myClassTestPackage;
```

declared in both, I get a `ClassNotFoundException` when I try to run it.

What causes this issue and how can I fix it?  This is the simplest way I was able to reproduce an error I am experiencing in a much larger program.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

That's because the [Class.forName() method](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/Class.html#forName(java.lang.String)) takes the fully qualified class name as parameter.

```
Parameters:
    className - the fully qualified name of the desired class.
```

So:

```
Class.forName("myClassTestPackage.MyClass");
```

Comment: I kind of thought it would be something like that.  Thank you.  I appreciate it.